# Pattern or language tool for a single used event?

Tags: c#, .net, events, design-patterns

I find myself often in the need of the following code scenario

Subscribe to to the event -> wait for the  event -> unsubscribe from the event.

is there any better way than:

```
myEvent += mydelegate;
while (mydelegatewasn't called)
{
     // do stuff
}   
myEvent -= mydelegate;
```

also what is the best way to wait for my delegate to finish its work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spinning in a while loop, you might want to consider taking a look at the [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) class to wait for your delegate to finish its work. This avoid spinning while waiting for your delegate to finish.

```
void Main()
{
    RunActionOnceOnEvent(delegate()
    {
        // do stuff
    });
}

void RunActionOnceOnEvent(Action action)
{
    AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    EventDelegate handler = delegate() 
    { 
        autoResetEvent.Set(); 
    }); 

    myEvent += handler;

    try
    {
        autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
        action();
    }
    finally 
    {
        myEvent -= handler;
    }
}
```

In terms of reducing the amount of boilerplate code for different events, I'm not sure you'll be able to do much since events are not first-class.

Comment: If the AutoResetEvent was created on a thread-local scope. It would be okay new instance of the AutoResetEvent is created for different threads.

Comment: In the case of two threads firing the event simultaneously the action will be executed twice.